# Can't send JSON data to other activity Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am quite new to Android. 
What I am trying to do:
I downloaded data in JSON format through API. I am trying to Bundle it with some other data and send it over to my second activity. 
My logic behind it is that I created a global variable "JSONData" and assigned the data I downloaded to it in "onPostExecute". 
However when I try to send it through Intent (in a bundle) to the second activity only the first piece of data shows up. 
My guess is that the bundle is sent before the JSON data is downloaded. 
The data is definitely downloaded through API as I displayed it using TextView. 
Anyone could give me some tips please on how to solve that??
I would be very grateful :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String JSONData;
private TextView Data_Test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TestView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TestView);
}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            return  buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JSONData = result;
        /*Data_Test.setText(JSONData);*/


    }
}


public void btnType0(View view) {
    new JSONTask().execute("URL_with_API");
    String activity_title = getResources().getString(R.string.housing_button);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("title", activity_title);
    extras.putString("JSON_Object", JSONData);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In my second activity I receive the bundle as such:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_data);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String activity_title = bundle.getString("title");
    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtView.setText(activity_title);

    String JSONData = bundle.getString("JSON_Object");
    TextView txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_test);
    txtView1.setText(JSONData);

}
```

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433703/my-questions-is-how-do-i-pass-the-list-data-i-have-obtained-from-json-in-a-frag/42434427#42434427

Comment: You have to change the json data to string and then change the string back to json where you receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man you are doing wrong!!

`new JSONTask().execute("URL_with_API");` you can not get value in JSONData variable because you have declared it global were your assigning value in `AsyncTask`
which is background process, so this line will be went in background and next line will be executed immediately. below

```
String activity_title = getResources().getString(R.string.housing_button);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("title", activity_title);
extras.putString("JSON_Object", JSONData);// so here JSONData always being null
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

You have to start activity in `onPostExecute` like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String activity_title = getResources().getString(R.string.housing_button);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("title", activity_title);
        extras.putString("JSON_Object", result);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



public void btnType0(View view) {
    new JSONTask().execute("URL_with_API");
}
```

> Or just pass Url in required activity and fetch data in that activity using url in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayDataActivity.class);
 //Bundle extras = new Bundle();
intent.putString("title", activity_title); intent.putString("JSON_Object", JSONData);
// intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For send data

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
       intent.putString("title", activity_title);
       intent.putString("JSON_Object", JSONData);
       startActivity(intent);
```

For Recieve data

```
    String activity_title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");

    String JSONData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("JSON_Object");
```